# Filtering adjacent words in Makefile list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to manipulate some C flags in a gnu makefile, and I need to extract some two-word parameters from the flags (so for example `-mllvm`'s are followed by whitespace and then a sub-parameter.   I would need to remove the `mllvm` and the subsequent word)

```
CFLAGS := -DFOO -DBAR -mllvm llvmflag1 -mllvm llvmflag2
OTHER_CFLAGS := ??   #should be -DFOO -DBAR
MLLVM_FLAGS  := ??   #should be -mllvm llvmflag1 -mllvm llvmflag2
```

Unfortunately, I'm not seeing a straight-forward way of doing this.   The `$(filter)` does not work, because the search parameter is assumed to be a space-delimitted list of words, and the pattern is multiple words.   `$(patsubst)` also seems to not work, as according to the man page, it:

> Finds whitespace-separated words in text that match pattern...

But I need to match multiple words, not just words.   I'm wondering if there's any clever trickery that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use a recursive call function.  Maybe something like this:

```
removearg = $(if $2,$(if $(filter $1,$(word 1,$2)),$(call removearg,$1,$(wordlist 3,$(words $2),$2)),$(word 1,$2) $(call removearg,$1,$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2))))

keeparg = $(if $2,$(if $(filter $1,$(word 1,$2)),$(word 1,$2) $(word 2,$2) $(call keeparg,$1,$(wordlist 3,$(words $2),$2)),$(call keeparg,$1,$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2))))

CFLAGS := -DFOO -DBAR -mllvm llvmflag1 -mllvm llvmflag2

OTHER_CFLAGS := $(call removearg,-mllvm,$(CFLAGS))
MLLVM_FLAGS := $(call keeparg,-mllvm,$(CFLAGS))
```

Basically, removearg checks if the first word in the list is equal to the first argument (`-mllvm`) and if so skips the first and second words by calling itself recursively starting with the third word; if it's not it expands to the first word then calls itself recursively starting with the second word.

The keeparg function is the same but expands to the two first words if `-mllvm` else skips the next word.

*ETA*

Actually, here's a simpler way:

```
removearg = $(filter-out $1^%,$(subst $1 ,$1^,$2))
keeparg = $(subst $1^,$1 ,$(filter $1^%,$(subst $1 ,$1^,$2)))

OTHER_CFLAGS := $(call removearg,-mllvm,$(CFLAGS))
MLLVM_FLAGS := $(call keeparg,-mllvm,$(CFLAGS))
```

This assumes you'll never have an option starting `-mllvm^` in your `CFLAGS`.  If so, choose some other never-existing character besides `^`.

Comment: I think it also relies on exactly one space between the flag and its argument. `$(strip)` it in advance to avoid tripping over too many spaces.

Comment: I think I can safely make the assumption that only one space exists between the -mllvm and the subsequent parameter (I can add an assertion if `OTHER_CFLAGS` has the substring `-mllvm` afterwards to be sure).

Comment: @Vroomfondel -- just looked up strip, and it apparently removes double spaces between words.   This would indeed reslove any double spacing issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a helper library, [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has by coincidence ;) the supporting functions to solve your task programmatically:

```
$(call while, $$(call glob-match,$(space)$$(CFLAGS),*-mllvm *),\
   tmp := $$(call glob-match,$(space)$$(CFLAGS),*-mllvm *)$(newline)\
   rest := $$(call spc-unmask,$$(word 3,$$(tmp)))$(newline)\
   llvm_flg := $$(firstword $$(rest))$(newline)\
   CFLAGS := $$(firstword $$(tmp)) $$(call tail,$$(rest))$(newline)\
   $$(info [[[$$(tmp) --- $$(rest) --- $$(CFLAGS) ]]])$(newline)\
   MLLVM_FLAGS+=$$(llvm_flg),\
MLLVM_FLAGS := $$(strip $$(MLLVM_FLAGS))$(newline)\
CFLAGS := $$(call spc-unmask,$$(CFLAGS))\
)
```

- Condition: as long as glob-match returns a match of -mllvm in CFLAGS. There is a small trick to avoid an empty match on the first *: we sneak a $(space) character in at the beginning of the string so that the match will never be empty.
- Body (notice the quoting of the newlines - this is necessary for $(eval) to correctly interpret the code):

  - Extract the output of glob-match into a temporary variable (spaces are replaced in this output, see glob-match). The output is a list of three elements: all characters (*) up to -mllvm , the string -mllvm itself (notice the space at the end) and all characters (*) following it.
  - Convert back the third element (rest of CFLAGS behind the first -mllvm match) into a string with spaces and put it into rest
  - Pluck the argument to the -mllvm flag (which is the first element of rest) into llvm_flg
  - Modify CFLAGS to contain everything except -mllvm and its argument
  - Print the variables as a debugging aid - remove this in production of course
  - Append the newly found argument of the -mllvm flag to the output variable
- Exit statements:

  - Pretty-print MLLVM_FLAGS
  - Remove the space replacement characters from CFLAGS which have accumulated during the loop

Output:

```
[[[ -DFOO§-DBAR§ -mllvm§ llvmflag1§-mllvm§llvmflag2 --- llvmflag1 -mllvm llvmflag2 --- -DFOO§-DBAR§ -mllvm llvmflag2 ]]]
[[[ -DFOO§-DBAR§§ -mllvm§ llvmflag2 --- llvmflag2 --- -DFOO§-DBAR§§  ]]]
CFLAGS = -DFOO -DBAR
MLLVM_FLAGS = llvmflag1 llvmflag2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer, but MadScientist's was simpler.  I unfortunately can't upvote due to reputation.